# Stereo Microphone Output into Mono Input

Tags: audio, microphone

I'm not at all familiar with microphones, so sorry if this is a very simple issue. I have a Sony XAV-AX1000 headunit in my car and the standard microphone included with the kit. It's very similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017Y3J7GI) cheap unit and has a simple 3.5mm TS output. I'm trying to replace it with a Rode Video Micro, a microphone with a 3.5mm TRS output in what the datasheet calls 'dual mono'. When I plug the Rode microphone into the headunit I get no microphone input unless I play with the positioning very lightly and leave it maybe 2mm out from being totally plugged in. It's crystal clear in that position.

How do I fix this and what portions of the barrel do you suspect are connected in this position? Would [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002N1XMPO) work?

[image: TRS]

Comment: Could you please show us both ends of the cable, and point out the end that is NOT working correctly.

Comment: almost sounds like the Rode uses an unconventional pinout...maybe with the ring as ground?  shame they don't specify that on the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

@maxmclau The so called dual-mono configuration seems to provide a (sometimes independently controllable) copy of the monoral camera audio output, allowing this to be used for e.g. unforseen strong audio bursts during non-repeatable shot-taking. Likely (no more than that) the 3.5mm TS-TRS-adapter piece can help you out. I suspect that the TRS connection is of the conventional Tip=signal1, Ring=signal2, and Sleeve=ground/screen, with the Rode taking signal1 and signal2 as the two mono outputs. The TS configuration in your car-unit may contain shorting switches which makes a short-circuit between signal1 and/or signla2 to ground. The adapter piece you suggest may overcome this. Give it a try!

Comment: So you're thinking the TS jack is making contact with the TRS tip correctly, but then contacting the ring as if it were ground? I'll buy that adapter and report back.